# PHP/.htaccess - Redirect visitor when accessing page with .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my visitors to get redirected when they access pages with .php extension name. To make it a bit clearer:

I currently have .htaccess set to remove .php extension from URL in which when visitor types in www.mysite.com/about/ it loads the www.mysite.com/about.php content. I basically want the same thing happen in reverse like:

When visitor enters www.mysite.com/about.php into the address bar, I want to load the same content, but redirect/change the URL to www.mysite.com/about/ and appear in the address bar.

Thanks in advanced!
Paul G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
# To externally redirect /index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\sindex(\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Just a little issue here. Now, when type www.mysite.com/index.php the URL turns to www.mysite.com/index/ (which I don't like) How can I 301 redirect "www.mysite.com/index/" and "www.mysite.com/index.php" to just "www.mysite.com/"?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this seemed to work for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R]
```

Essentially this throws away the .php from your url and keeps everything else.

Comment: How do I go about implementing this on localhost(it doesn't seem to work)? I want to test it first locally before I make change on live server.

Comment: You can put the code in a .htaccess file where your web app is. Alternatively, if you have a virtualhost defined for your app in your httpd.conf file, you can put the code there.